# Selected list item color moves on scrolling the listView in Android

Tags: android, android-listview

In my Android application I am using listview. The code for list view is as follows

```
 <ListView
    android:id="@+id/inputselect_listview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:footerDividersEnabled="true"
    android:headerDividersEnabled="true"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
    android:splitMotionEvents="true" >
 </ListView>
```

When user selected one item from the listview then background color of list item changes according to this line

```
android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
```

EDIT: list_selector.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_selected="true"
    android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
<item android:state_selected="true"
    android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:state_selected="false"
    android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
<item android:state_selected="false"
    android:drawable="@color/blue_train" />
</selector>
```

list_selector.xml is in drawable folder to specify color.
Now the problem is that when I select one item from listview and scrolls the list then selected item background color also move downward/upward according to scrolling.
Please provide me solution so that selected item background color remains as it is on scrolling.

EDIT:Here the screenshot of scrolling listview by selecting single item.Blue color remains as it is

[image]

Please advice.

Comment: seems you are using state_focused instead of state_pressed show list_selector.xml

Comment: list_selector.xml  is updated now in question

Comment: Similar Question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36697055/android-listselector-still-partly-visible-when-the-item-is-scrolled-out

Answer (score 1):

seems uncleared states in selector causing this . use one like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 

  <!-- Selected --> 
  <item 
    android:state_focused="true" 
    android:state_selected="false" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/focused"/> 

  <!-- Pressed -->
  <item 
    android:state_selected="true" 
    android:state_focused="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/pressed" /> 

<!-- default -->
  <item  android:drawable="@drawable/default" /> 

</selector>
```

Comment: I updated the .xml file same but the issue is not solved yet.

Answer (score 0):

add line in getView() method;
convertView.setBackgroundResource(selectedItemInAactivityList.contains.(arrayListSetInAdaptor.get(position) ? r.drawable.selected : R.drawable.transperant));

This one line solved your problem

Answer (score 0):

Store clicked/selected positions in a set or array in your  onItemClick() method. 
Write code to handle color in getview() method of your adapter using stored positions.